# Is there any popular notation or name for a set having only elements 0 and 1?

Tags: notation

A binary variable is very well used in many engineering problems.

Suppose that we need to introduce some variables that indicate whether a computer is being used by a customer or not. Then, we may express it as $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ for computer $i$. If we have 100 computers, we may use $\mathbf{x}=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{100}$. In this case, we can write $\mathbf{x}\in\{0,1\}^{100}$ or $\mathbf{x}\in\{0,1\}^{100\times1}$.

Like an above example, $\{0,1\}$ is very well used. Is there any notation or name for $\{0,1\}$?

For example, we have $\mathbf{1}_{N\times M}$ and $\mathbf{0}_{N\times M}$ to express a set (or a matrix) with all-ones elements or all-zero elements.

Comment: I do not think that there is something better than what you mentioned.

Comment: The whole $\mathbf{x}$ will be called a bit vector or binary vector but usually no special name is given to the $\{0,1\}$ itself.

Comment: Your last examples differ from $\{0,1\}$ by only one character. The $\{0,1\}$ is already very short. So whatever alias you come up with, it will either be longer or of pretty much the same size. What's the point then? On the other hand $\{0,1\}$ is straight forward and easy to understand.

Comment: Let me give you another example. Whenever I use $S^n$ I always explain at least once what it means. But that's because the definition of $S^n=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ |\ \lVert v\rVert=1\}$ is a lot longer.

Comment: In Set Theory the usual  name for $\{0,1\}$ is $2$. [In the same way, the name of $\{0\}$ is $1$.]

Comment: Thant you all. Thanks to your comments, I knew that there are no speical names for $\{0,1\}$. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in mathematics it's usually just called $\{ 0, 1 \}$. Sometimes it's identified with the set of [truth values](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/truth+value) but as far as I know there isn't standard notation for that either. One could contemplate using $\mathbb{B}$ for "Boolean" but this is not at all standard.

$\{ 0, 1 \}$ as a set is an example of a type of object called a [subobject classifier](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject+classifier) in category theory, the standard notation for which is $\Omega$. But that's not at all a standard way to refer to $\{ 0, 1 \}$ either.

Finally, in some contexts it is just referred to as  $2$, but that's likely to be confusing if you don't explicitly note it.

Comment: *One could contemplate using* $\mathbb{B}$ *for "Boolean"* --- Probably not a good choice given what a [Boolean valued model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model) is.